# Why my mysql table has to optimize frequently

Tags: mysql, optimization, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql table with 12 columns, one primary key and two unique key. I have more or less 86000 rows/records in this table.
I use this mysql code:

```
INSERT INTO table (col2,col3,-------col12) VALUES ($val2,$val3,----------$val12) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2=VALUES($val2), col3=VALUES($val3),----------------col12=VALUES($val12)
```

When I view the structure of this table from cpanel phpmyadmin, I can see 'Optimize Table' link just below the index information of the table. If I click the link, the table is optimized.

But my question is why I see the 'optimize table' link so frequently (within 3/4 days, it appears) in this table, while the other tables of this database do not show the optimize table link (They show the link once in a month or even once in every two months or more).

As I am not deleting this table row, just inserting and if duplicate key found, just updating, then why optimization is required so frequently?

Comment: do you have innodb_file_per_table enabled?

Comment: Do you update a column in a unique key?

Comment: No, It is not innodb structured table, it's engine is MyISAM

Comment: No, unique key columns are not being updated in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** switch to Innodb

MyISAM storage engine uses BTree for indexes and creates index files. Every time you insert a lot of data this indexes are changed and that is why you need to optimize your table to reorganize the indexes and regain some space.

MyISAM's indexing mechanism takes much more space compared to Innodb.

Read the link below
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/

There are a lot of other advantages to Innodb over MyISAM but that is another topic.

Comment: InnoDB uses B-trees for indexes also. You are likely to get worse insert performance with InnoDB due to its clustered index.

Comment: yes true it uses B-tree but it stores them differently. No that was true back in a day not anymore. if you configure innodb correctly it out performs MyISAM in every case. Not to mention having MVCC which prevents locking and makes backups easier

Comment: Not that I can think of but if you are in MySQL older than 5.6 MyISAM is the only storage engine that has fulltext search. but innodb is now supporting fulltext search

Comment: The second part of the answer is that *phpmyadmin is only guessing* based on an arbitrary formula. Just because a tool suggests that an action is appropriate, doesn't mean that you should believe it, particularly any tool that allegedly has an idea that will help you optimize or otherwise "tune" your server.  Sometimes the automated advice is just a waste of time; other times it can be detrimental to performance.  Sadly, MyISAM also is the only engine that supports spatial (R-Tree) indexes, but if you aren't already using them, you likely don't have an application for them. +1 InnoDB ftw.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain how inserting records affects a MyISAM table and explain what optimizing does, so you'll understand why inserting records has such a large effect.

**Data**

With MyISAM, when you insert records, data is simply appended to the end of the data file.

Running optimize on a MyISAM table defrags the data, physically reordering it to match the order of the primary key index. This speeds up sequential record reads (and table scans).

**Indexes**

Inserting records also adds leaves to the B-Tree nodes in the index. If a node fills up, it must be split, in effect rebuilding at least that page of the index.

When optimizing a MyISAM table, the indexes are flattened out, allowing room for more expansion (insertion) before having to rebuild an index page. This flatter index also speeds searches.

**Statistics**

MySQL also stores statistics for each index about key distribution, and the query optimizer uses this information to help develop a good execution plan. Inserting (or deleting) many records causes these statistics to become out of date.

Optimizing MySQL recalculates the statistics for the table after the defragging and rebuilding of the indexes.

**vs. Appending**

When you are appending data (adding a record with a higher primary key value such as with auto_increment), that data will not need to be later defragged since it will already be in the proper physical order. Also, when appending (inserting sequentially) into an index, the nodes are kept flat, so there's no rebuilding to be done there either.

**vs. InnoDB**

InnoDB suffers from the same issues when inserting, but since data is kept in order by primary key due to its clustered index, you take the hit up front (at the time it's inserted) for keeping the data in order, rather than having to defrag it later. Still, optimizing InnoDB does optimize the data by flattening out the B-tree nodes and freeing up unused (deleted) keys, which improves sequential reads (table scans), and secondary indexes are similar to indexes in MyISAM, so they get rebuilt to flatten them out.

**Conclusion**

I'm not trying to make a case to stick with MyISAM. InnoDB has superior read performance due to the clustered indexes, and better update and append performance due to the record level locking versus MyISAM's table locking (assuming concurrent users). Also, InnoDB has ACID.

Still, my goal was to answer your direct question and provide some technical details rather than conjecture and hearsay.

Neither database storage engine automatically optimizes itself.